# VBA Copy Data goes wrong

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CopyTMR()

Dim sheet_number As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim last_row As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim tmr As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set tmr = wb.Sheets("Team Member Rules")


' Counting the sheets number
sheet_number = Worksheets.Count
'MsgBox sheet_number
'MsgBox "Before you continue, make sure all sheets has the Header at the first row"

' Clearing existing TMR in the sheet4
tmr.Select
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Clear

' If there more than 4 sheets, then we copy from the 5th until the last tab to 4th (TMR)
If sheet_number > 4 Then
    ' Loop  to copy any sheet after TMR tab to the TMR Tab
    For counter = 5 To sheet_number

        ' Selecting the corresponding tab to copy
        Worksheets(counter).Select ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        ' The Header is not copy
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Copy

        ' Moving back to TMR Tab to paste data
        tmr.Select
        ' Selecting the last row of TMR bab before pasting data after it
        last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & last_row + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next
End If

' Best fit
tmr.Select
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ColumnWidth = 100
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True  End Sub
```

Hi All!
I am having some issue with the code above.
For some reason it works fine for a while and then stop with "run-time error 1004".

What I am trying to do is to copy the content "without the header" of all the tab   after the 4th and paste them into the 4th tab.

Any tip or idea could help.
Thanks,

Comment: You really should take some additional debugging steps. At which point does the error occur; or, if it occurs at multiple points, where does it occur? Also, it would make it easier for others to help you, if you tried to remove the parts of the code that are not needed for your issue to come up.

Comment: I'm going to bet it's your use of .Select.  Avoid using that and work directly with the ranges.

Comment: Hi guys,

The error actually is happening around the select:

`Worksheets(counter).Select ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .CurrentRegion with .Offset. A variant array will assist in avoiding the clipboard altogether.

```
Sub CopyTMR()

    di w as long, arr as variant

    for w = 5 to worksheets.count
        with worksheets(w)
            arr = .cells(1,1).currentregion.offset(1,0).value
        end with

        with worksheets(4)
            .cells(.rows.count,"B").end(xlup).offset(1, -1).resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr
        end with
    next w

end sub
```